# How to use gsl integration in a cython prange block?

Tags: cython, gsl

To make things more general, take the `gsl_integration_qag` for example(since it needs a workspace to manage intervals).

Here is a deliberately designed simple example(`problem.pyx`):

```
from libc.math cimport cos
from cython.parallel import prange
from cython_gsl cimport *

cdef double mean(double[:] arr):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef double sum_ = 0.0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        sum_ += arr[i]
    return sum_ / arr.shape[0]

cdef double integrand(double x, void *params) nogil:
    cdef double a = (<double*>params)[0]
    cdef double b = (<double*>params)[1]
    return a*x + b

def use_gsl_integration_sequential():
    cdef double result, error
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef double result_sum=0.0
    cdef double results[3]
    cdef double a=0.0, b=0.0
    cdef double da = 0.1
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000

    cdef gsl_function gsl_func
    cdef double params[2]
    gsl_func.function = &integrand

    cdef gsl_integration_workspace *ws
    ws= gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(3):
        a += da
        result_sum = 0.0 # reset the sum(thank J.J.Hakala for pointing out this)
        for j in range(4): # here may be range(100000) in practice!
            b = a + j
            params[0] = a; params[1] = b
            gsl_func.params = params
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func, 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8, space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws, &result, &error)
            result_sum += result
        results[i] = result_sum

    gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws)
    # do some other stuff with the 'results', for example:
    return mean(results)


# Now, I want to parallel the inner loop
def use_gsl_integration_parallel():
    cdef double result, error
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef double result_sum=0.0
    cdef double results[3]
    cdef double a, b
    cdef double da = 0.1
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000

    cdef gsl_function gsl_func
    cdef double params[2]
    gsl_func.function = &integrand

    cdef gsl_integration_workspace *ws
    ws= gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(3):
        # a should be read-only in the follow prange block.
        a += da 
        # here may be prange(100000,...) in practice!
        for j in prange(4, nogil=True): 
            # b should be local private.
            b = a + j

            # params also should be local private
            params[0] = a; params[1] = b

            # gsl_func is shared, only its params differ.
            # According to the gsl manual(see follow link), workspaces should be allocated on a per-thread basis, but how?
            gsl_func.params = params
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func, 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8, space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws, &result, &error)

            result_sum += result

        results[i] = result_sum
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws)
    return mean(results)
```

A little long code, just for completely(for copy), but I think rather simple(to read)(๑•ᴗ•๑)

Then compile & link:

```
cython -a -2 problem.pyx

gcc -O3 -fopenmp -c problem.c -o problem.o -IC:\gsl2.1x86\include -IC:\python-2.7.10\include

gcc -shared -fPIC -fopenmp -o problem.pyd -LC:\gsl2.1x86\libs -LC:\python-2.7.10\libs problem.o -l:libgsl.a -l:libgslcblas.dll.a -l:libpython27.dll.a
```

In IPython:

```
In [1]: from problem import *
In [2]: use_gsl_integration_sequential()
Out[2]: 7.2
```

The result of `use_gsl_integration_parallel()` is undefined, I tried several times, at most time, it will crash, with some lucky, got a undefined value, so there must be something wrong! I just cannot find such a parallel example. Would somebody help me?

**Environment:**

> win10-64bit, gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0 32bit, python-2.7.10 32bit, cython0.24, gsl-2.1

**Some useful references?:**

https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL

https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Thread_002dsafety.html#Thread_002dsafety

(sorry, cannot post more info, two links is my limit...

Comment: I think `gsl_func` also needs to be local. I'm also not 100% sure it'll treat `result` as local here (I don't know that it doesn't though!)

Comment: Indeed, what confused me much is where to "allocate" these stuff(gsl_function, params, workspace). At first glance, it appears to be easy - easy to parallel, but I am wrong. Additionally, the [omp's cython support](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-prange#simple-usecases) is rather weak and implicit(violates "Explicit is better than implicit"). I begin to doubt whether the question is possible in cython. In fact, any C code example would help(although, I am not that familiar with using omp in C.)

Comment: I think you use a parallel block, allocate it in there. Then use a prange inside the parallel block. I can't actually test this out right now though so I can't promise it's right.

Comment: @DavidW more strange phenomenon arised: In my original function, I add a `int num_threads` parameter , and pass it to prange's `num_threads` kwarg, when translated to C, cython will complain: `optimization.c: In function '__pyx_f_12optimization_target_func0':  error: '__pyx_v_num_threads' undeclared (first use in this function) #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:__pyx_v_integrate_sum) num_threads(__pyx_v_num_threads)`. But I can't reproduce it in the simple example above. Is this due to the nested block you mentioned? I am totally confused, I'll do more research then.

Comment: ps: If I add a local variable, say `num_therads = num_therads`, at the function level, then cython won't complain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested that code, I got segmentation fault (linux, gcc 4.9.2).

I think the original code has the following problems

- four threads share multiple variables, each should have their own
- same working space used in those threads

The following version gives 7.2. Is the sequential version actually correct, since it does not set `result_sum = 0.0` in

```
for i in range(3):
    a += da
    result_sum = 0.0
```

```python
from openmp cimport omp_get_max_threads, omp_get_thread_num

def use_gsl_integration_parallel():
    cdef double result
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef double result_sum
    cdef double results[3]
    cdef double results2[4]
    cdef double a
    cdef double b[4]
    cdef double error[4]
    cdef double da = 0.1
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000

    cdef gsl_function gsl_func[4]
    cdef double params[4][2]
    cdef int tid

    cdef gsl_integration_workspace ** ws = <gsl_integration_workspace **>malloc(omp_get_max_threads() * sizeof(gsl_integration_workspace *))

    for j in range(omp_get_max_threads()):
        ws[j] = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(3):
        a += da

        for j in prange(4, nogil=True):
            tid = omp_get_thread_num()
            b[tid] = a + j

            params[tid][0] = a;
            params[tid][1] = b[tid]

            gsl_func[tid].function = &integrand
            gsl_func[tid].params = params[tid]
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func[tid], 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8,
                                space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws[tid],
                                &results2[j], &error[j])
            # printf("tid %d\n", tid)
        results[i] = sum(results2)

    for j in range(omp_get_max_threads()):
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws[j])
    free(ws)

    return mean(results)
```

Comment: Cool! I was somewhat misleaded by the cython prange example, I think them(params, gsl_func,...) will be automatically made local private, and then "copied" by each thread(forgive such fool thought). I  set about reforming my codes, now I am faced with a new problem: such integration will be called heavily and frequently, and thus can't afford to malloc and free these huge arrays(results, params,) locally, my idea is allocating them somewhere else once, then just checking these buffer in the integration, finally freeing them somewhere properly. Any better suggestion?@J.J. Hakala

Comment: i.e., in the example above,  change the loop to: `for i in range(1000): ... for j in range(1000000), ...`, how to properly deal with these arrays ( ╹◡╹)

Comment: @oz1 I moved `gsl_integration_workspace_alloc` out of the loop in `use_gsl_integration_parallel()` since those are reusable and allocating/deallocating them repeatedly was not a good idea. The other space allocations for arrays are stack allocations, so they are not costly. That workspace allocation should probably be only for maximum amount of threads `openmp.omp_get_max_threads()`, and then inside the loop `ws[openmp.omp_get_thread_num()]` instead of `ws[j]'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got the idea [workspaces should be allocated on a per-thread basis](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Thread_002dsafety.html#Thread_002dsafety), workspace is per-thread shared! but what matters most is 'The other space allocations' in practice, the `results2`, `error`, `... ` sometimes may be tens of thousands of length, so they can't stay on stacks, and the `use_gsl_integration_parallel` will be called in a huge iterating loop---every loop it may be called dozens of times...oh, it may be somewhat off-topic, I should refactor my code then.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @J.J.Hakala, I finally figure out how to make these stuff work. I reformed the example, and did some simple profile.  I just post it here, hope oneday it will be helpful to some newbees(as with me) in scientific computing.

**If there is any mistake, please correct me. Thanks!**

```
# cython: cdivision=True
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.math cimport sin
from cython.parallel import prange
from cython_gsl cimport *
cimport openmp

cdef double arr_sum(double *arr, size_t arr_len):
    cdef size_t i
    cdef double sum_ = 0.0
    for i in range(arr_len):
        sum_ += arr[i]
    return sum_

cdef double arr_mean(double *arr, size_t arr_len):
    return arr_sum(arr, arr_len) / arr_len

# A random chosen integrand function for demo.
cdef double integrand(double x, void *params) nogil:
    cdef double a = (<double*>params)[0]
    cdef double b = (<double*>params)[1]
    return sin(a*x + b)

def sequential_solution(int outer_loops, int inner_loops):
    cdef double result, error
    cdef size_t i, j
    cdef double result_sum=0.0, mean_val
    cdef double *results = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * outer_loops)
    cdef double a=0.0, da = 0.1
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000
    cdef gsl_function gsl_func
    cdef double params[2]

    gsl_func.function = &integrand
    cdef gsl_integration_workspace *ws = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(outer_loops):
        a += da
        result_sum = 0.0
        for j in range(inner_loops):
            params[0] = a; params[1] = a + j
            gsl_func.params = params
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func, 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8, space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws, &result, &error)
            result_sum += result

        results[i] = result_sum

    mean_val = arr_mean(results, outer_loops)
    gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws)
    free(results)
    return mean_val


def parallel_solution(int outer_loops, int inner_loops, int num_threads):
    cdef size_t i, j
    cdef double a = 0.0
    cdef double da = 0.1
    cdef double mean_val = 0.0
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000

    # Heavy malloc!
    cdef double *outer_results = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * outer_loops)
    cdef double *inner_results = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops)
    #cdef double *error = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops)
    cdef double error # Ignore the integration abserror in parallel
    cdef gsl_function *gsl_func = <gsl_function*>malloc(sizeof(gsl_function) * inner_loops)
    cdef double *params = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops * 2)
    cdef gsl_integration_workspace **ws = <gsl_integration_workspace**>malloc(sizeof(gsl_integration_workspace*) * num_threads)
    for i in range(num_threads):
        ws[i] = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(outer_loops):
        a += da
        for j in prange(inner_loops, nogil=True, num_threads=num_threads):
            error = 0 # local private.
            params[2*j] = a; params[2*j+1] = a+j
            gsl_func[j].function = &integrand
            gsl_func[j].params = params + 2*j

            # ws[openmp.omp_get_thread_num()] guarantees each thread shares it's own workspace,
            # since workspace is resuable in a thread. If two thread access the same workspace, data will corrupt.
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func[j], 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8,
                                space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws[openmp.omp_get_thread_num()],
                                &inner_results[j], &error)

        outer_results[i] = arr_sum(inner_results, inner_loops)

    mean_val = arr_mean(outer_results, outer_loops)

    # Now, free
    for i in range(num_threads):
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws[i])
    free(ws)
    free(params)
    free(gsl_func)
    #free(error)
    free(inner_results)
    free(outer_results)
    return mean_val

def parallel_solution_ver(int outer_loops, int inner_loops, int num_threads):
    cdef size_t i, j
    cdef double a = 0.0
    cdef double da = 0.1
    cdef double mean_val = 0.0
    cdef size_t space_size = 1000

    cdef double *outer_results = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * outer_loops)
    #cdef double *inner_results = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops) 
    cdef double inner_result, inner_result_sum # no need to malloc a inner_results 
    #cdef double *error = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops)
    cdef double error  # Ignore the integration abserror in parallel
    cdef gsl_function *gsl_func = <gsl_function*>malloc(sizeof(gsl_function) * inner_loops)
    cdef double *params = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double) * inner_loops * 2)
    cdef gsl_integration_workspace **ws = <gsl_integration_workspace**>malloc(sizeof(gsl_integration_workspace*) * num_threads)
    for i in range(num_threads):
        ws[i] = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(space_size)

    for i in range(outer_loops):
        a += da
        inner_result_sum = 0.0  # reduction(+: inner_result_sum)
        for j in prange(inner_loops, nogil=True, num_threads=num_threads):
            inner_result = 0.0  # local private.
            error = 0  # local private.
            params[2*j] = a; params[2*j+1] = a+j
            gsl_func[j].function = &integrand
            gsl_func[j].params = params + 2*j

            # ws[openmp.omp_get_thread_num()] guarantees each thread shares it's own workspace,
            # since workspace is resuable in a thread. If two thread access the same workspace, data will corrupt.
            gsl_integration_qag(&gsl_func[j], 0.0, 1.0, 1e-8, 1e-8,
                                space_size, GSL_INTEG_GAUSS15, ws[openmp.omp_get_thread_num()],
                                &inner_result, &error)
            inner_result_sum += inner_result

        outer_results[i] = inner_result_sum

    mean_val = arr_mean(outer_results, outer_loops)

    # Now, free
    for i in range(num_threads):
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(ws[i])
    free(ws)
    free(params)
    free(gsl_func)
    #free(error)
    #free(inner_results)
    free(outer_results)
    return mean_val
```

**update: there is no need to malloc a `results` array, added a updated solution `parallel_solution_ver` which I think is better, although It has nearly the same efficiency with `parallel_solution`**

In IPython Notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
from problem import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

max_exp = 20

times_seq = []
for loops in [2**n for n in range(max_exp)]:
    res = %timeit -n 1 -r 5 -o sequential_solution(10, loops)
    times_seq.append((loops, res))

times_p = []
for loops in [2**n for n in range(max_exp)]:
    res = %timeit -n 1 -r 5 -o parallel_solution(10, loops, 8)
    times_p.append((loops, res))

times_p_ver = []
for loops in [2**n for n in range(max_exp)]:
    res = %timeit -n 1 -r 5 -o parallel_solution_ver(10, loops, 8)
    times_p_ver.append((loops, res))

time_results = [times_seq, times_p, times_p_ver]
labels = ["sequential solution", "parallel solution", "parallel solution_ver"]
colors = ['r', 'y', 'g']
markers = ['s', '+', 'o']
line_params = [
    {"sequential solution": {"color": "r", "marker": "s", "ms": 6}},
    {"parallel solution": {"color": "g", "marker": "+", "ms": 20, "mew": 1}},
    {"parallel solution_ver": {"color": "b", "marker": "o", "ms": 6}}
]

for results, param in zip(time_results, line_params):
    loops = [res[0] for res in results]
    times = [res[1].best for res in results]
    plt.loglog(loops, times, label=param.keys()[0], **param.values()[0])
plt.xlabel("inner loops")
plt.ylabel("exec time (ms)")
plt.legend(loc=0)

print "loops        sequential  parallel    parallel_ver"
for s, p, p_v in zip(times_seq, times_p, times_p):
    print "n = {:6d}   {:f}s   {:f}s   {:f}s".format(s[0], s[1].best, p[1].best, p_v[1].best)

# Same result? Yes!
print sequential_solution(10, 2**19)  # 0.0616505777102
print parallel_solution(10, 2**19, 8)  # 0.0616505777102
print parallel_solution_ver(10, 2**19, 8)  # 0.0616505777102
```

[image]

```
loops        sequential  parallel    parallel_ver
n =      1   0.000009s   0.001450s   0.001450s  
n =      2   0.000016s   0.001435s   0.001435s  
n =      4   0.000032s   0.001447s   0.001447s  
n =      8   0.000063s   0.001454s   0.001454s  
n =     16   0.000125s   0.001396s   0.001396s  
n =     32   0.000251s   0.001389s   0.001389s  
n =     64   0.000505s   0.001387s   0.001387s  
n =    128   0.001016s   0.001360s   0.001360s  
n =    256   0.002039s   0.001683s   0.001683s  
n =    512   0.003846s   0.001844s   0.001844s  
n =   1024   0.007717s   0.002416s   0.002416s  
n =   2048   0.015395s   0.003575s   0.003575s  
n =   4096   0.030817s   0.006055s   0.006055s  
n =   8192   0.061689s   0.010820s   0.010820s  
n =  16384   0.123445s   0.020872s   0.020872s  
n =  32768   0.246928s   0.040165s   0.040165s  
n =  65536   0.493903s   0.079077s   0.079077s  
n = 131072   0.987832s   0.156176s   0.156176s  
n = 262144   1.975107s   0.311151s   0.311151s  
n = 524288   3.949421s   0.617181s   0.617181s
```